# Eval code in re.sub as in php

Tags: python

In PHP a can do it

```
$str = preg_replace("~^(<.*?>)([0-9a-zа-яё]){1}(.*?)~eu", "'$1 '.mb_strtoupper('$2', 'UTF-8').'$3'", $str);
```

How i can do it in python?

I try this, but it didnt works..

```
str=re.sub("~^(<.*?>)([0-9a-zа-яё]){1}(.*?)~eu", "\\1 \\2.upper()\\3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a string that can execute arbitrary functions is a security risk. Instead, you can supply a function instead of a string that will do the whole thing.

```
def repl(match):
    return "{0} {1}{2}".format(match.group(1), match.group(2).upper(), match.group(3))

text = re.sub("~^(<.*?>)([0-9a-zа-яё]){1}(.*?)~eu", repl, text)
```

Also, note that `str` is not a good name for a string since it shadows the `str` built-in function.